# Keyboard shortcut for code error details in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut to display the code error details in IDEA?
When I have some syntax error when writing Java code in IDEA, I have to place my cursor on the top of code before IDEA will tell me what's wrong.

[image: Error details being displayed in IDEA]

I don't want to move my hand from keyboard to mouse when I am typing. I just want to move my cursor to the error area and push a shortcut key then I know what's going on with my code. I've installed the ideaVim plugin.

Comment: Even your image is invalid, please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA, you can use Ctrl + F1 to solve this problem.

PS. Sorry that my english is bad and not make my question clear.